# How to make bar thicker in Kendo UI chart?

Tags: kendo-ui

[image]

My chart has a calories vs time data. The calories has values every 15 min. I want to make the bars closer. I am posting a sample of the data and also a link to the jsFiddle. Also, is it possible to have the entire 24 hours displayed on the chart and show only the ones which are having values...

```
  var data=  [{"IntraDayFifteenMinuteActivityKey":443124,"id":"abcd","datetimedata":"7/20/2014 4:15:00 AM","caloriesOut":"17","distance":"0","elevation":"0","floors":"0","steps":"0","createddate":"7/20/2014 12:00:00 AM","distanceunit":"Km"},
    {"IntraDayFifteenMinuteActivityKey":443125,"id":"abcd","datetimedata":"7/20/2014 4:30:00 AM","caloriesOut":"20","distance":"0","elevation":"0","floors":"0","steps":"0","createddate":"7/20/2014 12:00:00 AM","distanceunit":"Km"},
{"IntraDayFifteenMinuteActivityKey":443126,"id":"abcd","datetimedata":"7/20/2014 4:45:00 AM","caloriesOut":"17","distance":"0","elevation":"0","floors":"0","steps":"0","createddate":"7/20/2014 12:00:00 AM","distanceunit":"Km"},
    {"IntraDayFifteenMinuteActivityKey":443127,"id":"abcd","datetimedata":"7/20/2014 5:00:00 AM","caloriesOut":"17","distance":"0","elevation":"0","floors":"0","steps":"0","createddate":"7/20/2014 12:00:00 AM","distanceunit":"Km"},
    {"IntraDayFifteenMinuteActivityKey":443128,"id":"abcd","datetimedata":"7/20/2014 5:15:00 AM","caloriesOut":"17","distance":"0.00442800018936396","elevation":"0","floors":"0","steps":"6","createddate":"7/20/2014 12:00:00 AM","distanceunit":"Km"},
    {"IntraDayFifteenMinuteActivityKey":443129,"id":"abcd","datetimedata":"7/20/2014 5:30:00 AM","caloriesOut":"17","distance":"0","elevation":"0","floors":"0","steps":"0","createddate":"7/20/2014 12:00:00 AM","distanceunit":"Km"}]




                    $("#IntraDayDataChart").kendoChart({
                        dataSource: data,
                        seriesColors: [color],
                        chartArea: {
                            background: ""
                        },

                        title: {
                            text: "Intraday Data",
                            font: "14px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif bold"
                        },

                        legend: {
                            visible: false,
                        },

                        chartArea: {
                            background: ""
                        },

                        seriesDefaults: {
                            type: "column",
                            overlay: {
                                gradient: "none"
                            },
                            gap: .1
                        },
                        series: [{
                            name: type,
                            field: type
                        }],

                        categoryAxis: {
                            field: "datetimedata",                             
                            majorGridLines: {
                                visible: false
                            },
                            majorTicks: {
                            visible:false
                            },
                            type: "date",    
                            baseUnit: "minutes",
                            labels: {
                                dateFormats: {
                                    minutes: "h tt"
                                },
                                step:180
                            }                               
                        },
                        valueAxis: {
                            majorGridLines: {
                                visible: true
                            },
                            majorTicks: {
                                visible:false
                            },
                            labels: {
                                visible: false
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: type,
                                font: "14px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"
                            },
                            visible: false
                        },

                        tooltip: {
                            visible: true,
                            template: '#=kendo.toString(new Date(dataItem.datetimedata),"g")# <br />  #=kendo.toString(Number(dataItem.' + type + '),"n2")# ' + type
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

[Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5A9QY/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your chart lines thicker you need to decrease the gap in the series.

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  series: [ {
    gap: 0
  }]
});
```

Here is the API reference
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/dataviz/chart#configuration-series.gap

They have a tutorial of how to do this on the fly as well.
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/gap-spacing

---

For only displaying the time with data you would have to define the CategoryAxis as type 'category' instead of type 'date'. When you define it as a date kendo will fill in all the missing data points with blank so that it looks right. For this to work you may have to convert you dates to something that will order right as a category.

You instead could have kendo auto aggregate your data such that it will chunk together time. You can set this by setting the baseUnit in the CaregoryAxis to 'fit'

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  categoryAxis: {
    baseUnit: "fit"
  }
});
```